# Non-mapped form, EntityType and data attribute

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I use an `EntityType` to create a form, but not mapped on an entity. The form is long and the user re-use the same options many times, then when he valid the form, if it's valid, I store the `$form->getData()` in session.

When I generate the form I inject the `$data`. It works well for all options, except the `EntityType`, I don't understand why...

In the `$data`, I've an `ArrayCollection` with the objects selected in the `EntityType`, but the form doesn't select it. I've used `mapped = false`, because if I remove it I've an error:

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

Someone I've an idea how to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings `mapped = false` shouldn't be the solution in this case, because you need to write the stored data into this field, right? so `mapped = false` avoid it (see more about `mapped` option [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped))

The problem here is that the `EntityType` need to get the `id` value from each *item* and it requires that these *items* are managed actually by `EntityManager`:

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

An entity is in `MANAGED` state when its persistence is managed by an `EntityManager`. In other words, an entity is managed if its fetched from the database or registered as new through `EntityManager#persist`.

In you case, these entities comes from session, so you have two option:

- Re-query the stored entities from database:

  ```
  if (isset($data['foo']) && $data['foo'] instanceof Collection) {
      $data['foo'] = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Foo::class)->findBy([
          'id' => $data['foo']->toArray(),
      ]);
  }
  ```
- Or, set a custom `choice_value` option to avoid the default one:

  ```
  $form->add('foo', EntityType::class, [
      'class' => Foo::class,
      'choice_value' => 'id', // <--- default IdReader::getIdValue()
  ]);
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've try the second method because more convenient to use. And It works, and thank for the explanations.